# Youtube upload with no authentication

Tags: php, api, youtube

I'm doing a bit of research into the Youtube API, but have not found an (negative or positive) answer to my question yet. The Youtube API Doc does give some answers as to how you can do a browser bases upload. My problem with that solution is that it sends the user to an youtube-url, and on upload finishing, it redirects to my site. I would like to somehow skip the step of having to being send to Youtube and then back again.

For me the ideal solution would be this:

1. I save my username and password in my database. I also save the id/name of the playlist users should upload videos to
2. When a user wants to upload a video, he or she does not have to authenticate them selves, because the already have been authenticated by the username and password I saved in my database. Så he or she select the video they want to upload, and it is uploaded to the playlist I also saved to my database.

I don't now if that is even possible - so I guess that's what I'm asking - is it even possible?

The other solution would be this:

1. The user uploads the movie to my site/server
2. Some cronjob then uploads the video to my channel and the specific playlist.

Is that possible?

Comment: so you want to double your bandwidth usage, by forcing people to upload to your one single server, rather than the vastly huge distributed "as close to the user as possible" google network, then have to upload it through your limited outgoing pipe to youtube anyways?

Comment: What you're looking to do involves CURL, I'm not 100% sure if YouTube has a captcha when uploading video nor do I think what you're trying to do complies with their TOS. Perhaps it's best to contact them, as they may have an API you can use.

Comment: @MarcB yeah it's a "dirty" solution, but for the benefit of my client, a have had to research every possible solution :-)

Comment: @Scowen I've done some more research and it doesn't seem possible - not even in the future. Haven't contacted them though - I might try that.